# "lives of people have remained a mystery" ...weird?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Consider this sentence:

> The lives of people whose tools and pottery have been found on its [Lake Titicaca's] shores have long remained a mystery.

Does this sound weird?

I'm particularly interested in the connection that "lives of people have remained a mystery".  This goes in contrast with the fact that we actually know little about their lives.  And even though they *are* connected with something we perceive as a mystery, the time span of the mystery goes far beyond the actual lives.  Does the tense use reflect this correctly?

Or could/should this be phrased differently, more clearly?

Comment: There's no mystery in the phrasing. It makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: Voting to close as a non-Q.

Comment: @Kris How is this a non-Q? (By the way, you have also answered it, even though you used comment for that.)

Comment: "close as a non-Q" is shorthand for one of the five or six preset justifications used when EL&U users vote to close a question.  The real language is: _Not a real question - It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form._ You've asked: _Does this sound weird? Should it be phrased differently? Could it be phrased more clearly? Is the tense correct?_ I suspect that these four questions put together make this "overly broad" in Kris' mind.

Answer (score 4):

It's not about the time spans of the people's lives, and it's not a contrast. If I say

> The lives of the people of Borneo have long remained a mystery to me.

I am stating a simple, uncomplicated fact. A mystery is something you know little about and causes you to wonder. That state of mind is not mysterious in and of itself.

Comment: Notice that @Robusto included the word "the" before "people".  I think that adding that word to the original sentence is all it needs.

Comment: @Simon Jester With 'whose' following it, I did not see a need for the definite article before 'people'.

Answer (score 3):

`This goes in contrast with the fact that we actually know little about their lives?`
It's actually in direct correlation. When you know little about someone's life, then his/her life is a mystery to you.

`Even though they are connected with something we perceive as a mystery, the time span of the mystery goes far beyond the actual lives.`
While there may be a mystery at the shores of Lake Titicaca, this sentence is dealing with the actual people who lived there, not the larger picture.

So, to answer your question: No, the sentence does not sound weird, and so does not have to be rephrased.